# First Order Logic translation

Tags: math, set, logic, predicate, jsoniq

Use the following definitions to represent English statements as first-order formulas.

Define:

●  - is a set of companies

●  - is a set of investors

●  = {(, , ) | (, , ) ∈  ×  ×  ∧   ℎ  ℎ   }-
investments

● (, , , ) - investment x describes investor i holding more than n shares of company c

Represent:
"Each company has at least one investor holding more than 100 of its shares"

Comment: 1) Please provide your attempts to solve this problem. 2) This question rather should posted at math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Also you post incomplete text  of the problem, set N is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and came up short. The way I approached it was:

∀x ∈ C.
∃y ∈ I. (so far)

Unfortunately the ICN and P(x,i,c,n) part is tripping me up, especially regarding n>100. I hope that I'm correct so far; hopefully someone with more knowledge can build off of/correct what I have.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to solve this and came with this solution:

```
∀c∈C. ∃i∈I. ∃x∈ICN. P(x,i,c,100)
```

Can someone confirm if this is the correct solution?